# unable to redirect the fURL in payumoney using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, payumoney

I integrated payumoney in my website and I am using codeigniter framework. I done this using bolt and every payment is succeeded but whenever a payment is failed it doesn't call the furl I passed to payumoney. I figure out the problem as below:
whenever a payment is failed it return back to the payu payment modal / popup to repay the payment but not execute the code written for failure response. And in case if I wait for autoclose the payu dialog box whatever the time it takes i.e. 10-15 minutes then it executes the failure code but conditionally i have to wait for its autoclose which is not acceptable and if after payment failed I close the payu dialog box it doesn't execute the failure code. I just want to know how to autoclose the dialog or execute the code.
Can anybody help to get out of this situation, any help will be appriciate.

Bolt code:

```js
function getHash()
{
      var course_id = $("#pro_id").val();
        $.ajax({
        url:  '<?php echo base_url();?>paymentprocess/payUMoney_Process',
          type: 'post',          
          data:{"course_id":course_id},
          success: function(data) {
            var responseData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(responseData.data);
            if(responseData.status = "200")
            { 
                 var response = responseData.data;
               
                launchBOLT(response);
            }
            else
            {
              alert("Something went wrong");
            }
          }
        });
}
```

here is my controller code:

```html
$data = array();
        $data["udf5"] = "BOLT_KIT_PHP7";
        $data['orderId'] = "order153";
        $data["surl"] = base_url()."paymentprocess/payumoney_success";
        $data["furl"] = base_url()."paymentprocess/payumoney_failed";
        $data["curl"] = base_url()."paymentprocess/payumoney_cancel";
        $data["key"] =  "TBBRlvO5"; 
        $data["salt"] =  "3JCjLwS8aa";
        $data["txnid"] = "Txn" . rand(10000,99999999);
        $data["amount"] = 1; //
        $data["pinfo"] =   $payTMData["course_name"];//"P01,P02";
        $data["fname"] =  $userdetail->first_name;
        $data["email"] =  $userdetail->email;
        $data["mobile"] = "";
        $data["hash"] = hash('sha512',  $data["key"].'|'.$data["txnid"].'|'.$data["amount"].'|'.$data["pinfo"].'|'.$data["fname"].'|'.$data["email"].'|||||'.$data["udf5"].'||||||'.$data["salt"]);
         $responseData = array("status" =>'200',"data"=>$data);
            echo json_encode($responseData);
```

here is the failure url function:

```html
function payumoney_failed()
    {
        if($_POST)
        {
         $a = 'POST';
        }else if($_REQUEST)
        {
         $a = "REQUESt";
        }
        else{
         $a = "none of the above";
        }
        $data = array(
          'demo' => $a
        );
        $this->Crud_model->SaveData('testing',$data);
    }
```

but whenever the payment failed it doesn't call the payumoney_failed() function. please help me. thanx in advance.

Comment: You gotta share your code for us to look.

Comment: hi I'd update my question hope it will help you to find my bug.

Comment: hi I got an answer for my own question,actually when i used payumoney's bolt feature it can't redirect to failure url but if I use payu's redirect feature then it did.

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of checkouts
1. Bolt checkout
2. Redirect checkout

In bolt checkout popup will appear when you click on pay button, in case of redirect it will redirect to PayU page.

In failed transaction scenario, in bolt checkout it will redirect to popup again for re-attempt and in redirect checkout it will redirect to failure URL.

Comment: As I am testing it from last 5 days, everytime I found this. but not confirmed as a solution i am not satisfied. but its fine.

Comment: I mailed the payu team for bolt redirection and they said the same thing about the checkout.

Comment: Then that must be the case.